# remember me functionality not working in android

Tags: android, authentication

I am new to Android development.In my code i used shared preferences to store and retrieve the username and password.I implemented this by one of the tutorial i studied.I created a one method namely remember() and called it when my check box is clicked in on click method.But when i clicked the check box and run my program unfortunately it gets stopped.

This is my code.Can anyone find where i did mistake?

```
public void onClick(View v) {
            if(chkbx.isChecked())
            remember();

            final TextView username =(TextView)findViewById(R.id.username);
            final TextView password =(TextView)findViewById(R.id.password);
            String uname = username.getText().toString();
            String pass =  password.getText().toString();


               String storedPassword=loginDataBaseAdapter.getSinlgeEntry(uname);
            if(!uname.equals("")  && !pass.equals("")&&pass.equals(storedPassword))
                startActivity(new Intent(LoginActivity.this,welcomeActivity.class).putExtra("usr",(CharSequence)uname));
             else 

                Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this,"Invalid UserName or Password", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();



        }
    });
```

This is remember method

```
private void remember(){

        final TextView username =(TextView)findViewById(R.id.username);
        final TextView password =(TextView)findViewById(R.id.password);
        String uname = username.getText().toString();
        String pass =  password.getText().toString();
        SharedPrefManager.SetName(uname); 
            SharedPrefManager.SetName(pass); 
         SharedPrefManager.StoreToPref();

        SharedPrefManager.LoadFromPref(); 
         String usrname,pswd;
        usrname = SharedPrefManager.GetName();
       pswd= SharedPrefManager.GetPass();


       EditText tv = null;
        tv = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.username);
        tv.setText(usrname);
        tv = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.password);
        tv.setText(pswd);

    }
```

Comment: Could `SharedPrefManager.SetName(pass); ` be the issue? I see you are storing the password in the username field (or at least that's what it appears to be). Do you have an equivalent method for storing the password (like you store the username), such as `SharedPrefManager.SetPass(String)`?

Comment: ya i have separate file sharedManager in that i defined setPass and setPass methods.i dont know where i did mistake?

Comment: After you retrieve the password, you are storing it using the `SetName` method (which you are using to store the username). Use `SharedPrefManager.SetPass(pass);` instead of `SharedPrefManager.SetName(pass);` in your `remember()` method

Comment: ya i changed it but nothing happens lucian

Answer (score 0):

Use following code for remember me function its working for me.
First create one class shown below

```
package com.example.fitnessapp;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.content.SharedPreferences.Editor;

public class SessionManager {

    SharedPreferences pref;
    Editor editor;
    Context context;

    int PRIVATE_MODE = 0;

    public static final String PREF_NAME = "FitPref";
    private static final String IS_LOGIN = "IsLoggedIn";
    public static final String KEY_USERNAME = "username";
    public static final String KEY_PASSWORD = "password";
    private boolean isChecked = false;

    public SessionManager(Context context) {
        this.context = context;
        pref = context.getSharedPreferences(PREF_NAME, PRIVATE_MODE);
        editor = pref.edit();
    }

    public void createLoginSession(String username, String password) {
        editor.putBoolean(IS_LOGIN, true);

        editor.putString(KEY_USERNAME, username);
        editor.putString(KEY_PASSWORD, password);
        if (isChecked == true) {
            editor.putBoolean("isChecked", true);
        } else {
            editor.putBoolean("isChecked", false);
        }
        editor.commit();
    }

    public void createLoginSession(String username, String password, boolean remember) {
        editor.putBoolean(IS_LOGIN, true);

        editor.putString(KEY_USERNAME, username);
        editor.putString(KEY_PASSWORD, password);
        editor.putBoolean("remember", remember);
        editor.commit();
    }

    public void checkLogin() {
        if (!this.isLoggedIn()) {
            Intent i = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);

            i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
            i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);

            context.startActivity(i);
        }
    }

    public boolean isLoggedIn() {
        return pref.getBoolean(IS_LOGIN, false);
    }
}
```

After that in your MainActivity use following code for store username and password.

```
if (remember.isChecked() == true) {
    sm.createLoginSession(user, pass, true);
   }
```

For retrieve back that username and password use following code.

```
SharedPreferences pref = MainActivity.this.getSharedPreferences(SessionManager.PREF_NAME, 0);
        boolean loggedIn = pref.getBoolean("remember", false);
        if (loggedIn == true) {
            remember.setChecked(true);
            String user = pref.getString(SessionManager.KEY_USERNAME, "");
            String pass = pref.getString(SessionManager.KEY_PASSWORD, "");

            username.setText(user);
            password.setText(pass);
        }
```

Hope it helps you.

Comment: Thanks Jitesh.I have one doubt over here.The variable sm is the object for SessionManager Class right?When i implement this in my code it asked me to initialise the sm variable to NULL.Is this correct

Comment: Yes But dont forget to check null condition if you assign sm = null